# MYSQL - Grab lowest column value row while keeping a WHERE statement

Tags: mysql

I would like to grab all `path`s from `product_images` that has `position` as 1 or closest to it (ASC).

**I'm trying to grab the first product image of each product from a specific category.**

Here's my query:

```
SELECT pi.product_id, path, position from product_images pi
JOIN product_categories pc ON (pc.product_id = pi.product_id)
WHERE pc.category_id = 59 
GROUP BY pi.product_id
ORDER BY pi.position ASC
```

What doesn't work with this is that it doesn't always grab the image that has position 1, instead it takes position 2 for some of the products.

I think this is because I `order by` position after the `group`ing (where it already took the random row)?

How can I make it order by correctly?

Table structures:

**product_categories**

```
category_id | product_id
```

**product_images**

```
id | product_id | path | position
```

Comment: What's the structure of the tables?

Comment: This is not a job for `GROUP BY`, anyway.

Comment: @axiac check updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why it doesn't work

You want some rows from table `product_image` but the result produced by `GROUP BY` does not contain rows from tables. `GROUP BY` computes the values it returns. More, the query you posted in the question is invalid SQL because the `SELECT` clause of a `GROUP BY` query is allowed to contain only these kinds of expressions:

- expressions that also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- expressions that use the [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html);
- columns that are functionally dependent on the columns that are present in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Only the `pi.product_id` column from the `SELECT` clause of your query is safe here. The other two columns would be allowed if you `GROUP BY pi.id`, f.e.

Until version 5.7.5, MySQL used to allow such invalid queries (while other RDBMSes reject them). However, the values returned for expressions that do not match any of the rules above were [indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). But you already found that (I quote you: *"where it already took the random row"*).

#### The solution

A query that should generate the results you need (I didn't test it) looks like:

```
SELECT pi.product_id, pi.path, pi.position
FROM product_categories pc
  INNER JOIN product_images pi         # product image
    ON pi.product_id = pc.product_id
  LEFT JOIN product_images bi          # better image...
    ON bi.product_id = pi.product_id   # ... of the same product
       AND bi.position < pi.position   # ... better because of `position`
WHERE pc.category_id = 59 
  AND bi.id IS NULL         # keep only when there isn't a match in "better image"
```

#### How it works

The query joins `product_categories` because it needs to select only the images of products from a specific category against table `product_images` (aliased as `pi`). This is what you already have in your query, I just swapped the order of the tables to make the query easier to read and understand. Next, it joins `product_images` again (aliased as `bi` from "better image", better in terms of `position`).

The join combines each row from the left table (which in this case is the join between `pc` and `pi`) with all the rows from the right table (`bi`). It matches each product image (from `pc JOIN pi`) with all the images of the same product that have a better `position`. Because it is a `LEFT JOIN`, it puts in the result set all the rows from the left table, even when there is no matching row in the right table. In this case, a row full of `NULL` values is used instead of the row from the right table.

Next, the `WHERE` clause filters only the products from the category we need and, more important, only the rows that have `NULL` in their part extracted from table `bi`. But these are the images that don't have a match in the "better image" table; i.e. they have the best (smallest) `position`.

Finally, the `SELECT` clause contains the needed columns from table `pi` (it can also contain columns from `pc`). All the columns from table `bi` that lands in the result set are `NULL` anyway.

Comment: Learned something new. Thank you!!